# How to perform full outer joins on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, full-outer-join

I'm new to MySQL and trying to perform a full outer join operation on 3 tables:

> Student:-
>
> > usn(Primary key)
> >
> > name
>
> plays :-
>
> > usn(foreign key)
> >
> > sport_id(foreign key)
>
> sport :-
>
> > sport_id(primary key)
> >
> > sport_name

I want to get names of Students who play some sports and if they don't play any, i want NULL (thus the full outer join),

I tried executing the query :

```
select student.name, sport.name 
from student 
full outer join plays on student.usn = plays.usn
full outer join sport on plays.sport_id = sport.sport_id;
```

But, i am getting an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join plays on student.usn = plays.usn 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3
```

Can you please tell me what is it that i am doing wrong...?

Comment: The accepted answer on the proposed duplicate is simply wrong -- and I don't care if it has 600+ upvotes.  It removes duplicates.  I'm not sure if the right thing to do in this situation is to reopen the question or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a `FULL JOIN`.  You want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select s.name, sp.name 
from student s left outer join
     plays p
     on s.usn = p.usn left outer join
     sport sp
     on p.sport_id = sp.sport_id;
```

A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table and matching rows in the subsequent tables -- which is exactly what you want.

`FULL JOIN` is rarely needed.  I write a lot of SQL and months go by without my using `full join` in any database.

In this example, a `FULL JOIN` would be used if you *also* wanted all sports that have no students.  That is `NULL` values could appar in any column.

Comment: Thanks, left join did the job for me!